# Filling a listbox with data from the database. The values from the database depend on the selection of an combobox-item C# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, mvvm

After selecting a value from my combo box, values should be added to the listbox from a database. In my case I select a school class from the combo box. The listbox should then show the students in this class(selected school-class from the combo box). The school classes are also from the database. 
The combobox is filled with school classes and I fill it using a method that I call up in the constructor. 
The students should be displayed after I click on a button. This click is done in a command which is bound to the command property of the button. 
The logic is in a ViewModel class and not in the Window.xaml.cs since I use MVVM here. The listbox is not filled with the data from the database, that's the problem. Nothing is displayed

Here are my Code from the ViewModel:

The Command Property:

```
public ICommand SearchCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (searchCommand == null)
            {
                searchCommand = new RelayCommand(() => searchStudents());
            }
            return searchCommand;
        }
    }
```

The Method:

```
public void searchStudents()
    {
        try
        {
            mySqlConnection.Open();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM `studentmanagement-db`.tbl_student WHERE FK_Klasse= @FK_Klasse;";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, mySqlConnection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FK_Klasse", KlasseProp.KlassenIDFK);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MySqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            using (sqlDataAdapter)
            {
                DataTable studentTable = new DataTable();
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(studentTable);
                var result = studentTable;
                SchuelerProp.Vorname = "Vorname"; 
                SchuelerProp.ItemSource = studentTable.DefaultView;
                SchuelerProp.SchuelerID = "tbl_student_id";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            mySqlConnection.Close();
        }
```

Here are the Bindings from the xaml:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="Combo_Klassen" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20,10,10,10" Width="100" Height="25"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=KlasseProp.ItemSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=KlasseProp.KlassenNamen}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding KlasseProp.KlassenIDFK}"
                      SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=KlasseProp.KlassenID}"
                      >
            </ComboBox>
            <Button x:Name="Button_Search" Content="search" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="20,10,50,10" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                    Command="{Binding Path=SearchCommand}"/>

            <ListBox x:Name="Listbox_Students" Margin="50,100,50,75"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SchuelerProp.ItemSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=SchuelerProp.Vorname}"
                     SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=SchuelerProp.SchuelerID}"
                     SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SchuelerProp.Schueler_ID}"
                    >
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: Obligatory don't use `AddWithValue`.  Use `Add(...).Value = ` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `UppdateSourceTrigger` to `OnPropertyChanged` for the `SelectedValue` like this: `SelectedValue="{Binding Path=KlasseProp.KlassenIDFK, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: Well ok, if you debug your function does it load the data from the sql database? Did you implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your ViewModels?

Comment: This line: `var result = studentTable;` is only for testing. When i was debugging i saw that the data from the database is loaded in `studentTable` but my Listbox ist Empty and yes i implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to my ViewModel